# Android kotlin Image picker and camera in same bottom sheet

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to provide option to pick image from gallary or take a picture from camera. I want it in a bottom sheet like the Android 13 `ACTION_PICK_IMAGES`but with camera option in that bottom sheet. Is there any action for that or I would do manualy / library. Is there any way to add button the the default bottom sheet of Android 13 `ACTION_PICK_IMAGES`?

Comment: There is no ACTION_PICK_IMAGE. There is ACTION_PICK_IMAGES.

Comment: ? You say that ACTION_PICK_IMAGES has every thing you want and then you ask how to implement it. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The new Android Photo Picker ,that is available only from API 30, is designed specifically and only for **choosing** media files. If you want your user to be able to also choose a photo via camera you need to implement that option separately.